# jhipster-uml TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: jhipster

Version : generator-jhipster 2.21.1 
Version : jhipster-uml 1.6.5

When i try to create new entity, i got the 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined'

```
D:\Advanze\workspace2\sms>jhipster-uml entity_Vendor_Support.jh
Creating:
        VendorSupport
        VendorSupportReply
Found the .jhipster/VendorSupport.json configuration file, automatically generating the entity
The entity VendorSupport is being created.
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at EntityGenerator.files (C:\Users\manson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\entity\index.js:1190:49)
    at C:\Users\manson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\base.js:429:16
    at runCallback (timers.js:649:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:622:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:594:5)


Found the .jhipster/VendorSupportReply.json configuration file, automatically generating the entity
The entity VendorSupportReply is being created.
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at EntityGenerator.files (C:\Users\manson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\entity\index.js:1190:49)
    at C:\Users\manson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\base.js:429:16
    at runCallback (timers.js:649:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:622:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:594:5)
```

Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
entity VendorSupport{
    title String required maxlength(255),
    description String required maxlength(4096),

    status String maxlength(20),
    createdBy String required,
    modifiedBy String required,

    created ZonedDateTime required,
    modified ZonedDateTime required
}
entity VendorSupportReply{

    description String required maxlength(4096),

    status String maxlength(20),
    createdBy String required,
    modifiedBy String required,

    created ZonedDateTime required,
    modified ZonedDateTime required

}
relationship ManyToOne {
    VendorSupportReply{VendorSupport} to VendorSupport
}
```

the jh file

Answer (score 0):

As you may have found, generator is failing on [this line](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/v2.21.1/entity/index.js#L1190)

```
enumInfo.enums = enumInfo.enumValues.replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
```

It seems that it thinks that one of your field is an enum, your JDL file has no enum in it so my guess is that it's due to `ZonedDateTime` field type which was not supported by JHipster 2.21.1.

So either you change this type or you update JHipster to a more recent version.